# How do I make a minimal and reproducible example for neural networks?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, pytorch

I would like to know how to make a minimal and reproducible deep learning example for Stack Overflow. I want to make sure that people have enough information to pinpoint the exact problem with my code. Is it enough to just provide the traceback?

```py
    c:\users\samuel\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py 
                         in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
        135                             ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have shape ' +
        136                             str(shape) + ' but got array with shape ' +
    --> 137                             str(data_shape))
        138     return data
        139
```

Or should I simply post the error message?

> Value Error: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape
>   (4,) but got array with shape (1,)

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few tips to make a **reproducible, minimal deep learning Example**. It's good advice whether it be for `Keras`, `Pytorch`, or `Tensorflow`.

- We can't use your data, but in most cases, it doesn't matter. All we need is the right shape.

  - **Use randomly generated numbers of the right shape.**

    - E.g., `np.random.randint(0, 256, (100, 30, 30, 3)` for 100 colored pictures of size *30x30*
    - E.g., `np.random.choice(np.arange(10), 100)` for 100 samples of 10 categories
- We don't need to see your entire pipeline.

  - **Only provide the bare minimum to run your code.**
- Make the most out of `Keras` and its debugging abilities.

  - **Include the traceback.** It will most likely point out the exact problem.
- Neural networks are all about fitting the right shapes.

  - **At a minimum, *always* provide the input shapes.**
- Make it easy to test and reproduce.

  - **Post your entire neural network architecture.**
  - **Include your library imports. Define all variables.**

Here is an example of a **perfect** minimal and reproducible example:

---

*"I have an error. When I run this code, it gives me this error:"*

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape (10,) but got array with shape

*"Here is my architecture, with generated data:"*

```py
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D

xtrain, xtest = np.random.rand(2, 1000, 30, 30, 3)
ytrain, ytest = np.random.choice(np.arange(10), 2000).reshape(2, 1000) 

model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=xtrain.shape[1:]),
    Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    Dense(10, activation='softmax')])

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(xtrain, ytrain,
          batch_size=16,
          epochs=10,
          validation_data=(xtest, ytest))
```