# How to change python program to get rid of nan loss when running the neural network

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

How to change my neural network multiclass classification imbalanced data set program to get rid of nan error on loss

```
encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(y_train)
encoded_Yone = encoder.transform(y_train)
# convert integers to dummy variables (i.e. one hot encoded)
dummy_yone = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Yone)
#encode our testing set
encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(y_test)
encoded_Ytwo = encoder.transform(y_test)
# convert integers to dummy variables (i.e. one hot encoded)
dummy_ytwo = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Ytwo)


model = Sequential()
 model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', input_dim=78 ))
 model.add(Dropout(0.5))
 model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
 model.add(Dropout(0.5))
 model.add(Dense(15, activation='softmax'))

 adam = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)

 model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
     optimizer=adam,
     metrics=['accuracy'])

 model.fit(x_train, dummy_yone,
     epochs=10000,
     batch_size=128,
          verbose=2,
          validation_split=0.2)
```

Error:

[image: nan error]

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOIVN.png)

Comment: Your question is very difficult to answer without critical information. Please provide more information regarding your input and input shape. _READ:_ [How do I make a minimal and reproducible example for neural networks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59437658/how-do-i-make-a-minimal-and-reproducible-example-for-neural-networks)

Comment: Are you sure your `dummy_yone` follows `(dummy_yone.sum(axis=-1) == 1).all() == True`?

Comment: Hi welcome to SO please consider adding some sample data

Comment: I made the changes requests if you guys could help it would mean a lot I'm just really stuck